# how are static arrays initialized in java if we are not creating any objects of that class

Tags: java, arrays, static, initialization

i have a static array as a data member of a class and i'm having all static functions so i'm not creating any objects hence not calling any constructor in that case how is my static array getting initialized and with what?

Comment: Consider that if static members were initialized when a constructor is called, they would be initialized *whenever* a constructor is called.

Comment: .......................hello?

Answer (score 0):

The type of field, static or instance, has nothing to do with object creation -- they are orthogonal concepts.

All "static" means is that the field is a class field, while non-static fields are instance fields, and if the field, be it static or instance, are reference (not primitive) fields, and if they are non-null, then the object that they refer to has been created somehow, somewhere.

For example, this code:

```
package pkg2;

public class Foo {
    String[] instanceArray = {"A", "B", "C"};
    static String[] staticArray = {"A", "B", "C"};
}
```

generates this bytecode:

```
public class pkg2.Foo {
  java.lang.String[] instanceArray;

  static java.lang.String[] staticArray;

  static {};
    Code:
       0: iconst_3
       1: anewarray     #11                 // class java/lang/String
       4: dup
       5: iconst_0
       6: ldc           #13                 // String A
       8: aastore
       9: dup
      10: iconst_1
      11: ldc           #15                 // String B
      13: aastore
      14: dup
      15: iconst_2
      16: ldc           #17                 // String C
      18: aastore
      19: putstatic     #19                 // Field staticArray:[Ljava/lang/String;
      22: return

  public pkg2.Foo();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #24                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0
       5: iconst_3
       6: anewarray     #11                 // class java/lang/String
       9: dup
      10: iconst_0
      11: ldc           #13                 // String A
      13: aastore
      14: dup
      15: iconst_1
      16: ldc           #15                 // String B
      18: aastore
      19: dup
      20: iconst_2
      21: ldc           #17                 // String C
      23: aastore
      24: putfield      #26                 // Field instanceArray:[Ljava/lang/String;
      27: return
}
```

showing that both array *objects* are created the same but are stored differently

Specifically -- both array objects are created the same:

```
   5: iconst_3
   6: anewarray     #11                 // class java/lang/String
   9: dup
  10: iconst_0
  11: ldc           #13                 // String A
  13: aastore
  14: dup
  15: iconst_1
  16: ldc           #15                 // String B
  18: aastore
  19: dup
  20: iconst_2
  21: ldc           #17                 // String C
  23: aastore
```

but are stored differently:

For the instance field:

```
  24: putfield      #26                 // Field instanceArray:[Ljava/lang/String;
```

and for the static field:

```
  19: putstatic     #19                 // Field staticArray:[Ljava/lang/String;
```